Can't connect to port 27017
I have tried running the following in Windows PowerShell:
Test-NetConnection -InformationLevel detailed -ComputerName portquiz.net -Port 27017

I get the following error message:
WARNING: TCP connect to (35.180.139.74 : 27017) failed
WARNING: Ping to 35.180.139.74 failed with status: TimedOut

I am able to connect to port 80 but not 27017. How do I enable access to port 27017 on Windows? I need access to this port for MongoDB Compass.
